# Why view model should never reference a view ? Is it only the Design [like SOC(separation of concerns)] or something else?

Tags: android

While I was going through the view model in the [Android developer manual link](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel#implement), I saw this caution.

**Caution: A ViewModel must never reference a view, Lifecycle, or any class that may hold a reference to the activity context.**

Is this only a SOC(Separation of Concern) Design decision or there is something internal to android system design which is the reason for this approach.

If it is only for testing the view model, then you again mock that file in view model and test it. Am I missing something more ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In a configuration change (e.g., screen rotation, multiwindow, keyboard availability), the activity and all of its UI elements (fragments, views, etc.) get recreated. The `ViewModel` does *not*. Instead, the re-created activity gets the same `ViewModel` as the original instance had.

If that `ViewModel` contains references back to the old activity (directly or indirectly), you have at least two problems:

1. You have a memory leak, as the old activity (and all that it references) cannot be garbage-collected while the `ViewModel` is outstanding
2. Anything you try to do with the old activity instance is likely to crash, as that activity has been destroyed